# Change a String of text from generated code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkout page on a site that generates a shipping message. I need to change the text of that shipping message.

Here is the path to the element needing changed:

```
#order_review > table > tfoot > tr.shipping > td > p
```

Here is the approach I'd like to take (correct me if a better one), but I need help drilling down to the right element:

```
var oldstring = "Enter your shipping information above to show shipping options."
var changeit = document.getElementById("order_review");
changeit.oldstring.replace("Enter your shipping information above to show shipping options.", "Enter your full address to verify free delivery.");
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#order_review > table > tfoot > tr.shipping > td > p")`

Comment: Strings are immutable. `replace` returns a new string. And you are may looking for the `textContent` property

Comment: @JonasW. more than that, the OP is trying to "update" the element itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `querySelector` method as Andereas mentioned in the comments. You don't need to use `replace`, simply assign the new text to `innerHTML` or `textContent`:

```
var changeit = document.querySelector("#order_review > table > tfoot > tr.shipping > td > p");
changeit.textContent = "Enter your full address to verify free delivery.";
```

If you want to keep the reference to the `order_review` and drill down from there, you can do this:

```
var changeit = document.getElementById("order_review");
changeit.querySelector("table > tfoot > tr.shipping > td > p").textContent = "Enter your full address to verify free delivery.";
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var qs = document.getElementById("order_review");
qs.querySelector("table > tfoot > tr.shipping > td > p").innerHTML = "Enter your full address to verify free delivery.";
```

```html
<div id="order_review">
  <table>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="shipping">
        <td>
          <p>Enter your shipping information above to show shipping options.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: **Question's title:** Change a String of text from generated code in **javascript**.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `textContent` when updating text on the DOM:

```
let el = document.querySelector("#order_review > table > tfoot > tr.shipping > td > p");
el.textContent = "Enter your full address to verify free delivery.";
```

Comment: Improved answer.